# Maven configuration for Multi Module Project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, multi-module

I am creating a multi-module project with Spring Boot, the project will have 3 modules: moduleA, moduleB and moduleC.

I am following this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/#scratch

in the root directory I've created the 3 directories: moduleA, moduleB and moduleC

I've run `mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper`

after I've run `sudo ./mvnw` and here the result:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-calzada:multi-module-project-example nunito$ sudo ./mvnw
/Users/nunito/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/multi-module-project-example
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.066 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-24T20:03:37+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
MacBook-Pro-de-calzada:multi-module-project-example nunito$
```

and executing `./mvnw clean install`

```
/Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/multi-module-project-example
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.062 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-24T22:38:20+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/multi-module-project-example). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
MacBook-Pro-de-calzada:multi-module-project-example nunito$
```

Comment: What is `mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper` meant to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `pom.xml` file in order to run `./mvnw clean install`.

> [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/multi-module-project-example).

Have a look at **Maven Configuration for Multi Module Project** and **Maven Configuration for Library** in the tutorial. There you will find the necessary `pom.xml` files.

Comment: That was my thought but reading the guide I will have the run the goal and afterwards add the pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

There are two things :

1. For running any maven project , the very basic and first requirement is you must have a `pom.xml` . Absence of this file will throw you the error :

   > [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there
   >   is no POM in this directory
   >   (/Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/multi-module-project-example).
   >   Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help
   >   1]
2. In the tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/#scratch it is mentioned that you should have the `pom.xml` file , please refer this section ***▶Maven Configuration for Multi Module Project***